# What is the best way to access deque's element in C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I have a deque:

```
deque<char> My_Deque;
My_Path.push_front('a');
My_Path.push_front('b');
My_Path.push_front('c');
My_Path.push_front('d');
My_Path.push_front('e');
```

There are such ways to output it.

The first:

```
deque<char>::iterator It;
for ( It = My_Deque.begin(); It != My_Deque.end(); It++ )
    cout << *It <<  " ";
```

The second:

```
for (i=0;i<My_Deque.size();i++) {
    cout << My_Deque[i] <<  " ";
}
```

What is the best way to access deque's element - through iterator or like this: `My_Deque[i]`?
Has a deque<...> element an array of pointers to each element for fast access to it's data or it provides access to it's random element in consequtive way (like on a picture below)?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An STL deque is usually implemented as a dynamic array of fixed-size arrays, so indexed access is perfectly efficient.

Answer (score 11):

Since you asked for "the best way":

```
for (char c : My_Deque) { std::cout << c <<  " "; }
```

Comment: What version of C++ do you need for something like this to work?

Comment: @tjwrona1992: C++11 or later.

Comment: It's too bad my company still lives in the stone age.  Oh well maybe in a few years when they finally upgrade I'll be able to make nice clean looking loops like this one.

Answer (score 2):

The standard specifies that `deque` should support random access in constant time. So yeah, `[i]` should be reasonably fast.

But there still might, I think, be an advantage to using the iterators. It could (theoretically at least) be a constant multiple faster (or slower maybe!). Anyway, every use of `[i]` will involve looking up some table(s) and calculating offsets and so on. I would imagine that `operator++` for deque::iterator is slightly more than just "find my offset; add 1 to it; lookup with the new offset"

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for "the best way":

```
std::copy(My_Deque.begin(), My_Deque.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
```

Admittedly, for formatting of individual object it won't make much of a difference but using the algorithms on segmented data structure *can* make a major difference! There is an interesting optimization possible when processing the segments individually when processing an entire range. For example, if you have a large `std::deque<char>` you want to write verbatim to a file, something like

```
std::copy(deque.begin(), deque.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
```

which is copying from one segmented data structure to another segmented data structure (under the hood stream buffers use a buffer of characters which becomes their segment) can take substantially less time (depending somewhat on the speed the data can be written to the destination, though).

Comment: Your `std::for_each` example won't compile. That algorithm expects a unary function object for the third parameter.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: This indeed true. Somehow I was too eager to match the answer of Kerrek SB. I will fix this: it should read `std::copy()`. Thanks!